# How to draw in cmd?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I found this code:
https://gist.github.com/k-takata/a5a56b9904da48ef8ee2e04161055a14

I tried to run it, but the compiler said:

> undefined reference to __imp_SetPixelV

I went to `wingdi.h` and discovered that the function `SetPixelV()` will be defined if `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)` is defined. I tried this code:

```c
#define WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(x) ((WINAPI_FAMILY) & (x))
#define WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP
```

But it got worse. Even basic Win32 APIs like `DWORD` were not defined.

I removed the previously said code and it went back to normal.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to link with the Windows libraries which contains the definitions of the Windows API functions. Read [the proper documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel) instead of finding dubious hints on the Internet.

Comment: As for what you're trying to do, drawing all over a window  that doesn't belong to your process is a rather nasty thing to do. And any code that contains a function like `IsWindows9x` should be looked upon with suspicion.

Comment: You cannot render into a device context you do not own. A console host is a window whose device context you do not own. If you need colorful console text, use [console virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) and have the console host deal with the visuals. As for trying things at random, that's not a tractable approach to software construction.

Comment: "undefined reference" is a *linker* error, not a *compiler* error. You don't need to mess around with the `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` stuff to fix this. Just make sure you are *linking* to your toolset's `gdi32.lib` import lib